# Converting Data Frame to Zoo. Trouble with Posixlt

Tags: r, dataframe, zoo

I am trying to convert a data frame to a zoo object and having quite a bit of trouble.  No matter what I do in the read.zoo call I get the below error.    I would think that it is not even necessary to list the format of the timestamp since it is already Posixlt but that is not the case.

Can you point me in the right direction?

```
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

This is a sample of the data,

```
                   Date   Open   High    Low  Close
330 2014-01-03 15:00:00 544.95 545.10 544.80 544.86
331 2014-01-03 15:01:00 544.80 544.89 544.77 544.79
332 2014-01-03 15:02:00 544.84 544.90 544.79 544.80
333 2014-01-03 15:03:00 544.80 544.80 544.60 544.69
334 2014-01-03 15:04:00 544.75 544.80 544.66 544.75
335 2014-01-03 15:05:00 544.78 545.03 544.76 545.01
```

Here is reproducible code:

```
require (zoo)

data <- structure(list(Date = structure(list(sec = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
), min = 0:5, hour = c(15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L), mday = c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), mon = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), year = c(114L, 
114L, 114L, 114L, 114L, 114L), wday = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L
), yday = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), isdst = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L)), .Names = c("sec", "min", "hour", "mday", "mon", "year", 
"wday", "yday", "isdst"), class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt")), Open = c(544.95, 
544.8, 544.84, 544.8, 544.75, 544.78), High = c(545.1, 544.89, 
544.9, 544.8, 544.8, 545.03), Low = c(544.8, 544.77, 544.79, 
544.6, 544.66, 544.76), Close = c(544.86, 544.79, 544.8, 544.69, 
544.75, 545.01)), .Names = c("Date", "Open", "High", "Low", "Close"
), row.names = 330:335, class = "data.frame")

data <- read.zoo(data, header = TRUE, index = 1, tz="", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the following is called right after your `data <- structure(…`

```
read.zoo( transform( data, Date = as.POSIXct(Date) ), FUN = identity )
```

it should get you going in the right direction. A `?read.zoo` should help in the understanding of what that does.

Comment: Unfortunately a current limitation of `read.zoo` is that it does not handle POSIXlt index input but the above answer, transforming it to POSIXct first, seems like a good approach. Another approach is to transform it to character first: `read.zoo( transform(data, Date = format(Date)), tz = "" )` ,

Comment: Thank you both for your comments.  It now works using hrbrmstr's code.  I wasn't ready for it to ignore a native R date format and it wasn't blatantly spelled out in the documentation.  I thought that putting the format in the read.zoo call would suffice.  I'll keep this is mind going forward.

Comment: Achim just fixed it in the development version (which is available via subversion now and will eventually be available on CRAN) so with that fix this works: `read.zoo(data)` .